# Is there a way to click the bottom left of a UiObject in UiAutomator?

Tags: java, android-uiautomator

I am trying to automate something in UiAutomator and I have a UiObject that contains text; a portion of it being a hyperlink. I can't isolate the hyperlink from the rest of the text, so I was hoping that I could just click on the portion of the UiObject that contains the hyperlink - which in this case is in the bottom left. I see there are public methods clickBottomRight() and clickTopLeft(), but is there a way to click the bottom left of a UiObject? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UiObject.getVisibleBounds()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiObject.html#getVisibleBounds()) to get the View coordinates, calculate where you want to click and then use [UiDevice.click(x,y)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#click(int,int)) to perform the click.